# Onblur or onchange check, using a php function in a registration form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to be able to check the text in a text-box after it has changed, and report what is wrong.
It is for a registration form.

This is a part of register.php where

```
<form action"" method="post">
<ul class="ul-reg">
<li>
<p>Username: </p><input name="username-field" type="text" onblur="someFunction()" /><span id="UsernamehelpText">      </span>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Then I would have a registerfunctions.php where i would store all the functions for checking lenght,char,maybe regex etc.. Its not really that important what functions i call. I just don't know how to call them.

Form what i have seen the span is where u post the errors, but if there is any other option im open for it, all i want is to be able to post the erorr text in the same line as the text-box

I have checked JavaScript and AJAX, but I am pretty new in this and don't really understand how it works.

Comment: Are you rendering the output of both register.php and registerfunctions.php in the same HTML document?

Comment: I don't really know what u mean :) I feel pretty stupid :)

Comment: There are two ways you can solve a problem like this. You can have some Javascript in your page that runs in the user's browser and validates the form before it can be submitted. Or you can create an AJAX call that sends the form's data to your server, and you can then have a PHP script validate it and send an answer back to your page to be displayed. Which of those two options are you trying to do?

Comment: I think i would like javascript to first validate(escaping html code and cheking it long enough, email valid) all the info, so the user would not send data to the server, as far as i know thats more secure. Then it would send the data to the server, validating it further, just checking if username and or email already exist, and then if all is ok. I would create a new entry in the user database. Do u think that is a smart and secure way or am i overcomplicating things?

Comment: It is smart, but it is not secure. As a rule, and validation that you perform in Javascript *must* be performed in PHP as well. Otherwise you are open to attack by a malicious user who bypasses your javascript validation (for example by simply writing a POST by hand instead of using your page). It's common to do the validation on both sides, though, because it's nicer for the user, like you say, if they don't have to wait.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have watched a few jQuery tutorial videos and i now understand how things work. U pointed me in the right direction so thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in comments I understand what you want.

First, an explanation. There are two places where validation occurs: In your frontend (your web page) and in your backend (in the PHP script that saves the posted values). Anything that you really don't want to save - for example unescaped SQL strings, too-long fields, and so on - *has* to be validated in PHP, because it is trivial to get around Javascript validation. For example, nothing is stopping someone from sending a POST to your server containing illegal values without even bothering to visit your webpage.

Even though you need to perform validation in the back-end, it's still user friendly to do the same validation in the front end, so the user doesn't have to wait as long to see an error. This also reduces traffic to your server. Something you probably want to do in a big project is to have some kind of system for writing validation rules centrally, and then using those rules to dynamically generate both PHP and Javascript validation. The advantage of doing that is that you don't duplicate your business rules in two places, but in a smaller project it's probably not worth the hassle.

Validation in the frontend looks about like this: You bind an event handler to an appropriate event or events (you can add onkeydown="validateUserName()" for example, so that the validation reacts a bit quicker), and update your warning text appropriately.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <ul class="ul-reg">
    <li>
      <p>Username: </p>
      <input id="username" name="username-field" type="text" onblur="validateUserName()" />
      <span id="UsernamehelpText"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateUserName() {
    var userNameElement = document.getElementById('username');

    //Do your work: Get the value of the user name field, check
    // the values against your validation rules...

    var helpText = document.getElementById('UsernamehelpText');
    if(isValid)
      helpText.innerHTML = "";
    else
      helpText.innerHTML = "Invalid!";
  }
</script>
```

In the backend, when you process the form, you then have to check the same rules in PHP to prevent illegal values from being posted either maliciously or due to an error in your Javascript. If an error is found, you don't save, instead you can just re-render the form with the submitted values in the input fields and a message indicating what was invalid - this allows the user to change their inputs without losing the values they submitted.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i wanted. I wanted to to both side validation so that it is both safe and user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it would look something like this:

```
function someFunction() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "checkStuff.php",
    data: $("input[name='username-field']").serialize,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == "correct") {
        $("#UsernamehelpText").html("Valid");
      } else {
        $("#UsernamehelpText").html("Invalid");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Your PHP could be something very simple that just checks the validity of the input and then echos "correct" if it is.

Comment: Could u make and example how do i call a function that is inside checkStuff.php from this script? And this script goes in the header right?

Comment: This script goes either in script tags in the header, or in an external js file that is linked to somewhere on your page.  You can't call a specific php function, you can only call the file itself.  Whatever the file echos will be sent back to your success function.

Comment: Oh, well i would like a specific function. Say that a textbox is the password, and i would like to see how long it is and what characters it has. Well i guess its time i study jQuery and AJAX some more :D

Comment: You could add a query parameter to the url and call a specific function depending on that from the php.  E.g. `checkStuff.php?field=password`

Comment: Yeah I have now some basic knowledge about jQuery so I can do this thy way i wanted. Tnx.